# What's the proper way to add UIKit Dynamics to UICollectionViewCells?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell, uikit-dynamics

I'm trying to use UIKit Dynamics to implement swipe-to-delete on my UICollectionViewCells. Things aren't going as planned, though. Here's the code in UICollectionViewCell's awakeFromNib method:

```
self.animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.contentView];

UICollisionBehavior *collisionBehavior = [[UICollisionBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.contentView]];
[collisionBehavior setTranslatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundaryWithInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, -20)];
[self.animator addBehavior:collisionBehavior];

self.gravityBehavior = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.containerView]];
self.gravityBehavior.gravityDirection = CGVectorMake(0, 0);
[self.animator addBehavior:self.gravityBehavior];

self.pushBehavior = [[UIPushBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.containerView] mode:UIPushBehaviorModeInstantaneous];
self.pushBehavior.magnitude = 0.0f;
self.pushBehavior.angle = 0.0f;
[self.animator addBehavior:self.pushBehavior];

UIDynamicItemBehavior *itemBehavior = [[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.containerView]];
itemBehavior.elasticity = 0.45f;
[self.animator addBehavior:itemBehavior];
```

But this is not working so well. This is what happens at launch with the code above:

[image: Dynamics fail]

That behavior seems to be mostly generated by UICollisionBehavior. If I comment it out, the container view with everything that's not the red background doesn't animate, but does show up offset a few points to the left.

Am I right to try to implement this within UICollectionViewCell? What's the right way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. It was pretty much a typo. The collision behavior was attached to the wrong object.

The right code should be

```
UICollisionBehavior *collisionBehavior = [[UICollisionBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.containerView]];

[collisionBehavior setTranslatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundaryWithInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, -20)];

[self.animator addBehavior:collisionBehavior];
```